# How Signal Integrity check in Altium Designer compares to HyperLynx?

Tags: altium, signal-integrity, hyperlynx

I've finally discovered how to simulate high-speed signals propagation on PCB using Altium Designer, and it looks easy to use & convinient.

I wonder,

1. how close to reality results from Altium signal Integrity check (provided that PCB layers are set up correctly, and proper models are used for drivers & receivers), and
2. what are main benefits of using (more well known/powerful) tools like HyperLynx?

Comment: I did a comparison to Cadence SigXplorer a while back that you may want to look at as well: http://www.ee-training.dk/tip/altium-signal-integrity-tool-part-i.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 1 and for HyperLynx, it can be pretty good. The main differences I have seen is over/undershoot isn't as bad as the tools predict. Also some vendor's IBIS models are better than others, taking into account packaging of the IC and providing monitoring at the die pad, rather than at the IC pin/ball.

For 2, there isn't much of a difference below 1 GHz. At higher speeds HyperLynx has an option that includes lossy transmission lines.